# setBackgroundTintList does not apply directly

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am applying the method setBackgroundTintList() on my AppCompatButton class as the following:

```
applyTintColor(this.appCompatButton, R.drawable.button_orange_color_state);
```

The method applyTintColor:

```
public void applyTintColor(@NonNull View view, @DrawableRes int color) {

    ColorStateList colorStateList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(view.getContext(), color);
    ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(view, colorStateList);
}
```

My button_orange_color_state.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Disable background -->
    <item android:color="@color/brand_secondary"
          android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <!-- Default background -->
    <item android:color="@color/orange"/>
</selector>
```

**Problem**:
After applying the method applyTintColor, the button take the shape with the default white transparent color instead of my orange color.
But I noticed, when I press the button, the button correctly take the color of the disable state, then after enabling the button again, the color goes to orange.
The only, but dirty way I found so far, is then to add the following piece of code at the end of my applyTintColor:

```
    view.setEnabled(!view.isEnabled());
    view.setEnabled(!view.isEnabled());
```

In that way, the button directly take into account the good orange color.

So I wondering if someone has a better idea to make things better here ?

Comment: After `setBackgroundTintList()` a call to `invalidate()` might be all you need.

Comment: Thx, but it does not change unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, if the view has already been laid out, after `view.setBackgroundTintList(tint)`, you can call `view.refreshDrawableState()`.